# Getting rid of extra output in JAVA While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a question with this program I wrote for class. It is functioning exactly the way I need it to except for one minor detail. My while-loop is adding an extra "+" on the end of my print statement.

```
public class Fractions
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        //-----declare variables-----
        int numOfFractions  = 0,
            numerator   = 0;
        double total    = 0;
        DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#0.##");
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        //----Welcome MSG------
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("\t* * * Welcome to Fractions * * * ");
        System.out.println("");

        //-----get numOfFractions------
        System.out.print("Enter the number of fractions: ");
        numOfFractions = stdIn.nextInt();

        //----begin loop-------
        numerator = 1;

        while(numerator <= numOfFractions)
        {

            while(numOfFractions > 0)
            {
                System.out.print("" + numerator + "/" + numOfFractions + " " + "+" + " ");
                total += (double)numerator / numOfFractions;
                numOfFractions--;
                numerator++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("The total: " + df1.format(total));
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("\nThanks for using the Fraction Adder program\n");


    } // end main
} // end pgm
```

[Here is a picture of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6ZGN.jpg)

Comment: Just replace df1.format(total) with df1.format( total.substring(0,total.length()-1)). (provided that the redundant + is the last character in your string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this a simplest approach can be by simply using if/else condition, try this:

```
public class Fractions
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // -----declare variables-----
        int numOfFractions = 0, numerator = 0;
        double total = 0;
        DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#0.##");
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        // ----Welcome MSG------
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("\t* * * Welcome to Fractions * * * ");
        System.out.println("");

        // -----get numOfFractions------
        System.out.print("Enter the number of fractions: ");
        numOfFractions = stdIn.nextInt();

        // ----begin loop-------
        numerator = 1;

        while (numerator <= numOfFractions)
        {

            while (numOfFractions > 0)
            {
                if (numOfFractions > 1)
                {
                    System.out.print("" + numerator + "/" + numOfFractions + " " + "+" + " ");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("" + numerator + "/" + numOfFractions + " ");
                }

                total += (double) numerator / numOfFractions;
                numOfFractions--;
                numerator++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("The total: " + df1.format(total));
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("\nThanks for using the Fraction Adder program\n");

    } // end main
} // end pgm
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you check if the element you want to print is the last (or the first) element and then add the separator, or not. Here's a simplified example, since I think it's easier to understand what's happening:

```
String[] arr = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0)
       System.out.print("+");

    System.out.print(arr[i]);
}
```

We print the separator `+` only for elements at `index > 0` and *before* the actual value. You could also reverse this and print the separator for all elements at `index < arr.length - 1` *after* the actual value.

When using Java 8 you could also use `StringJoiner` and print the contents after the loop, like this:

```
String[] arr = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("+");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    joiner.add(arr[i]);
```

In your code this would look something like this:

```
// ...
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" + ");
while (numerator <= numOfFractions) {
    while (numOfFractions > 0) {
        joiner.add(numerator + "/" + numOfFractions);

        total += (double) numerator / numOfFractions;
        numOfFractions--;
        numerator++;
    }
}

System.out.println(joiner.toString());
// ...
```